# Error type: Could not find a valid session key. The now familiar error

Tags: error, session, cookies, domain

I suddenly find myself unable to use most Admin functions in 5.43.  I'm not completely shut out though. I can still load the Membership Dashboard where it loads Contact names etc., but can't do a simple search for a Contact via Search > Find Contacts. That keeps throwing me back to the Advanced Search page with no results.

I can clear Caches on the Settings page, but not via Admin > System Settings which also throws the error.

No recent changes to either wp-config or civicrm.settings

I recently updated WP to 5.9.1. I reverted to 5.8.3, but no change.  How do I debug this on a live site? PHP 7.4.3 on Linux hosting with https. I'm at my wits end. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED — Earlier I had an issue with more than one active session, and the code I had put into my WP theme functions.php to "fix" it, now became the problem itself.  // if session status is active then close the session  //